# Flink EMR Deployment can't pick up Yarn context and executes only as a local application

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I'm deploying my Flink app on AWS EMR 6.2

Flink version: 1.11.2

I configured the step with:

```
Arguments :"flink-yarn-session -d -n 2"
```

as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/flink-jobs.html

Both the cluster and the step are in state 'running'.

The controller logs shows:

> INFO startExec 'hadoop jar
> /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-309XLKSZGN4V4/trigger-service-***.jar
> flink-yarn-session -d -n 2'

However, the syslog show that the application didn't pick-up on the Yarn context.

> ```
> 2021-02-24 13:19:57,772 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster (main): Starting Flink Mini Cluster
> ```

I pulled out the class name returned by `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment` in my app, and indeed it is `LocalStreamEnvironment`.

The application itself runs properly on the JobMaster instance as a local app.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the -n is deprecated in new versions of flink, so, per the advice from AWS support, I used this command instead:

```
flink-yarn-session -d -s 2
```

Arguments meaning:

> -d,--detached                   Start detached

> -s,--slots                 Number of slots per TaskManager

In addition, In order to make Flink was required create two steps:

`--steps '[{"Args":["flink-yarn-session","-d","-s","2"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","MainClass":"","ActionOnFailure":"CANCEL_AND_WAIT","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Yarn Long Running Session"},{"Args":["bash","-c","aws s3 cp s3://<URL of Application Jar> .;/usr/bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -p 2 -d <Application Jar>"],"Type":"CUSTOM_JAR","MainClass":"","ActionOnFailure":"CANCEL_AND_WAIT","Jar":"command-runner.jar","Properties":"","Name":"Flink Job"}]`'

The first uses command-runner.jar to execute

> flink-yarn-session -d -s 2

and the second uses command-runner.jarto download my application Jar from S3 and run the job with flink on yarn-cluster.